# My event in useAnimatedGestureHandler don't reload in function of layout, I don't know why?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I want to create a system of widgets that are draggable and interchangeable with each other

I managed to make them draggable and interchangeable unfortunately when the view that I am dragging is interchanged, the view shifts relative to the pointer because the react native "css" updates well and therefore changes the point origin of the translation is at the new place of the view but not the translation of the event in onActive of useAnimatedGestureHandler and therefore this creates this offset

`Home.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableHighlight, View} from 'react-native';
import {DraggableView} from "./components/DraggableView";
import {Icon} from "@rneui/themed";
import DraggableContainer from "./components/DraggableContainer";

export default function Home({navigation}) {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Home</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight>
          <Icon name="plus" type='ant-design' size={24}/>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      <DraggableContainer onDrag={(isNotDragging) => {
        navigation.setOptions({swipeEnabled: isNotDragging});
      }}>
        <DraggableView>
          <View style={[styles.box2, {backgroundColor: "#b5cbb7"}]}/>
        </DraggableView>
        <DraggableView>
          <View style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: "#d2e4c4"}]}/>
        </DraggableView>
        <DraggableView>
          <View style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: "#818479"}]}/>
        </DraggableView>
        <DraggableView>
          <View style={[styles.box3, {backgroundColor: "#9ba898"}]}/>
        </DraggableView>
        <DraggableView>
          <View style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: "#e4e9b2"}]}/>
        </DraggableView>
        <DraggableView>
          <View style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: "#dbe7bb"}]}/>
        </DraggableView>
        <DraggableView>
          <View style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: "#c4d8be"}]}/>
        </DraggableView>
      </DraggableContainer>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    padding: 10,
    minHeight: 50,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 26,
    fontFamily: 'Inter-Regular'
  },
  box: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2.2,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2.2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    zIndex: 0,
  },
  box2: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.05,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2.2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    zIndex: 0,
  },
  box3: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.05,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.05,
    borderRadius: 10,
    zIndex: 0,
  }
})
```

`DraggableContainer.js`

```js
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {Dimensions, ScrollView, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native";
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default function DraggableContainer({children, onDrag}) {
    const [scrollEnabled, setScrollEnabled] = useState(0);
    const [childrenIds, setChildrenIds] = useState(children.map((_, index) => index));
    const childrenLayouts = useRef(children.map((_) => ({x: 0, y: 0, height: 0, width: 0})));

    const DraggableManagement = {
        onLongPress: () => {
            console.log("onLongPress")
            if (onDrag) onDrag(scrollEnabled !== 0)
            setScrollEnabled((prev) => ++prev)
        },
        onRelease: () => {
            console.log("onRelease")
            if (onDrag) onDrag(scrollEnabled !== 0)
            setScrollEnabled((prev) => --prev)
        },
        onChangePosition: (id, position, afterOrBefore) => {
            setChildrenIds((prev) => {
                prev = prev.filter((item) => item !== id);
                const index = prev.indexOf(position);
                if (afterOrBefore === 'before') {
                    prev = [...prev.slice(0, index), id, ...prev.slice(index)];
                } else {
                    prev = [...prev.slice(0, index + 1), id, ...prev.slice(index + 1)];
                }
                return prev;
            })
        },
        onLayout: (id, layout) => {
            childrenLayouts.current[id] = layout;
        },
    }



    return (
        <>
            <ScrollView
                scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled === 0}
            >
                <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.gestureHandler}>
                    <View style={styles.container}>

                        {childrenIds.map((index) => {
                            return (React.cloneElement(children[index], {
                                ...DraggableManagement,
                                id: index,
                                key: index,
                                childrenLayouts: childrenLayouts.current,
                            }))
                        })
                        }
                    </View>
                </GestureHandlerRootView>
            </ScrollView>
        </>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        padding: 10,
        gap: 10,
    },
    gestureHandler: {
        flex: 1,
        minHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height
    },
    absoluteFill: {}
})
```

`DraggableView.js`

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {PanGestureHandler, TapGestureHandler} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
    Easing, Layout,
    runOnJS,
    useAnimatedGestureHandler,
    useAnimatedStyle,
    useSharedValue,
    withDelay,
    withRepeat,
    withSequence,
    withSpring,
    withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import * as Haptics from 'expo-haptics';
import {Dimensions, Text, TouchableHighlight, View} from 'react-native';
import {BlurView} from "expo-blur";


const ANGLE = 1.5;
const TIME = 100;
const EASING = Easing.elastic(0.5);
const ELASTIC = Easing.elastic(1.9);

function DraggableView({children, style, onLongPress, onRelease, onChangePosition, onLayout, childrenLayouts, id}) {
    const x = useSharedValue(0);
    const y = useSharedValue(0);
    const [longPress, setLongPress] = useState([]);
    const [draggable, setDraggable] = useState(false);
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);
    const rotate = useSharedValue(0);
    const scale = useSharedValue(1);

    const openMenu = () => {
        setMenu(true);
    }

    const closeMenu = () => {
        setMenu(false);
    }

    const onPressGesture = (event) => {
        if (event.nativeEvent.state === 2) {
            setLongPress([event.nativeEvent.absoluteX, event.nativeEvent.absoluteY]);
        }
        if (longPress.length === 2 && event.nativeEvent.state === 1 &&
            event.nativeEvent.absoluteX === longPress[0] &&
            event.nativeEvent.absoluteY === longPress[1] && !menu && !draggable) {
            if (onLongPress) onLongPress()
            openMenu();
            Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Heavy);
            const y = event.nativeEvent.absoluteY;
            if (y > Dimensions.get('window').height / 2) {
                setPosition(1);
            } else {
                setPosition(0);
            }
        }
        if (event.nativeEvent.state === 1
            || event.nativeEvent.state === 4
            || event.nativeEvent.state === 5) {
            setLongPress([]);
        }
    }

    const scaleRotateStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        transform: [{
            scale: scale.value,
        },
            {
                rotateZ: `${rotate.value}deg`
            }],
    }));

    useEffect(() => {
        rotate.value = 0;
        if (draggable) {
            scale.value = 1;
            rotate.value =
                withSequence(
                    withTiming(-ANGLE, {duration: TIME / 2, easing: EASING}),
                    withRepeat(
                        withTiming(ANGLE, {
                            duration: TIME,
                            easing: EASING,
                        }),
                        -1,
                        true
                    ),
                    withTiming(0, {duration: TIME / 2, easing: EASING})
                );
        }
    }, [draggable]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (draggable) {
            scale.value = 1;
            return
        }
        if (longPress.length !== 2 && !menu) {
            scale.value = 1;
            return;
        }
        scale.value =
            withDelay(150, withTiming(1.02, {duration: 350, easing: ELASTIC}))
    }, [longPress, menu]);

    const collision = (id) => {
        const XLeft = x.value + childrenLayouts[id].x;
        const YTop = y.value + childrenLayouts[id].y;
        const XLeftCenter = XLeft + childrenLayouts[id].width / 3;
        const XRightCenter = XLeft + childrenLayouts[id].width * 2 / 3;
        const YTopCenter = YTop + childrenLayouts[id].height / 3;
        const YBotCenter = YTop + childrenLayouts[id].height * 2 / 3;

        childrenLayouts.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (index === id) return;

            const XLeftItem = item.x;
            const YTopItem = item.y;
            const XCenterItem = item.x + item.width / 2;
            const XRightItem = item.x + item.width;
            const YBotItem = item.y + item.height;
            if (XLeftItem < XLeftCenter && XLeftCenter < XCenterItem && YTopItem < YTopCenter && YTopCenter < YBotItem) {
                if (onChangePosition) onChangePosition(id, index, "before");
            }
            if (XRightItem > XRightCenter && XRightCenter > XCenterItem && YTopItem < YBotCenter && YBotCenter < YBotItem) {
                if (onChangePosition) onChangePosition(id, index, "after");
            }
        });
        }

        const panGestureEvent = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
            onStart: (_, context) => {
                context.x = x.value;
                context.y = y.value;
            },
            onActive: (event, context) => {
                const translationX = context.x + event.translationX;
                const translationY = context.y + event.translationY;

                x.value = translationX;
                y.value = translationY;
                runOnJS(collision)(id, context)
            },
            onEnd: () => {
                x.value = withSpring(0, {
                    dampingRatio: 1,
                    stiffness: 100,
                    overshootClamping: false,
                    restDisplacementThreshold: 0.01,
                    restSpeedThreshold: 2});
                y.value = withSpring(0, {
                    dampingRatio: 1,
                    stiffness: 100,
                    overshootClamping: false,
                    restDisplacementThreshold: 0.01,
                    restSpeedThreshold: 2});
            },
            onFinish: () => {
                runOnJS(onRelease)();
                runOnJS(setDraggable)(false);
                runOnJS(setMenu)(false);
            }
        }, [x, y]);

        const panStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
            return {
                transform: [
                    {
                        translateX: x.value,
                    },
                    {
                        translateY: y.value,
                    }
                ],
            };
        }, [x, y]);

        return (
            <Animated.View style={[{zIndex: menu || draggable ? 10 : 0}, scaleRotateStyles]} onLayout={(event) => {
                let layout = {};
                layout.x = event.nativeEvent.layout.x;
                layout.y = event.nativeEvent.layout.y;
                layout.width = event.nativeEvent.layout.width;
                layout.height = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
                onLayout(id, layout);
            }} layout={Layout.duration(200)}>
                {
                    menu && (<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                        closeMenu();
                        if (onRelease) onRelease();
                    }}><BlurView intensity={25} style={styles.absoluteFill}/>
                    </TouchableHighlight>)
                }
                <TapGestureHandler
                    onHandlerStateChange={onPressGesture}
                    maxDurationMs={500}
                >
                    <Animated.View>
                        <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={panGestureEvent} enabled={draggable}>
                            <Animated.View
                                style={[
                                    panStyle,
                                    {...style},
                                ]}>
                                {children}
                            </Animated.View>
                        </PanGestureHandler>
                    </Animated.View>
                </TapGestureHandler>
                {
                    menu &&
                    <View style={{...styles.menu, ...(position ? {bottom: "102%"} : {top: "102%"})}}>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                            closeMenu();
                            setDraggable(true);
                        }}>
                            <Text style={{
                                color: "white",
                                textAlign: "center",
                            }}>Move widget</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                }
            </Animated.View>
        );
    }

    const styles = {
        menu: {
            position: "absolute",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(95, 97, 99, 0.95)',
            height: 120,
            width: 210,
            borderRadius: 30,
            zIndex: 10,
            alignSelf: "center",
        },
        absoluteFill: {
            zIndex: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: -Dimensions.get('window').height,
            left: -Dimensions.get('window').width,
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 2,
            height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 2
        },
    }

    export {DraggableView};
```

I tried to use the new Gesture from react-native-gesture-handler
with GestureDetector and Gesture.Pan()
but unfortunately I encounter the same behavior

I tried to recalculate the offset and remove it during the translation thanks to the onLayout on the first view but this gives a glitch effect

I tried to add a state in the dependencies of useAnimatedGestureHandler which updates when colliding between two views but that doesn't change anything